# Eclipse Juno C++ with microsoft 2010 C++ express does not create EXE files

Tags: c++, eclipse

Using Eclipse Juno 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit, I just switched from windows 7 32 bit to 64 bit and installed Eclipse Juno with C++ plugins as well as Microsoft Studio Express C++ 2010, After defining the required paths now the compiler creates the Object files except no EXE file is created during the BUILD process.

Has anyone experienced this and if you have what was the resolution.

Comment: If it creates object files, that means the compiler is working correctly. Which means that the linker is not be executed correctly

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with Windows 7 64 bit and Juno

I am running into the same situation.

Here is a forum post from Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385608

The bug does make reference to some work-arounds.

Thanks